# Initiate Derived class from Base constructor with additional variable

Tags: c++, c++11

Let's say I have a base class --

```
class Base {
 public:
  Base(int n) : num(n) {}
 private:
  int num;
};
```

How can I make derived class constructor to call the base constructor but also initialize its own additional variable? Assuming I can only modify Derived but not Base (say Base is some library I don't want to change)

```
class Derived : public Base {
 public:
   // This won't work, compiler will complain no viable constructor or so
   Derived(int n, int an) : Base(n), another_num(an) {};
   // This won't work either
   Derived(int n, int an) : Base(n) {another_num = an;}
 private:
  int another_num;
};
```

EDIT
The error message I'm getting:

```
no matching constructor for initialization of Derived
candidate constructor not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 1 was provided
```

This is an deprived example of something much more complicated that I'm working on.

Comment: That should work (assuming you don't actually have two `Derived` constructors with the same argument types). Please edit your question to add the exact error messages you get.

Comment: I have two constructors in the example, which one should work? Or both?

Comment: Which have you tried?

Comment: Both will work fine.

Comment: @clwen Both should work.

Comment: The code you have posted will absolutely compile and do exactly what you want. Why do you say in the comment that the compiler will complain?

Comment: OK. As edit suggests, this is a deprived version of something more complicated. Maybe something else is going wrong. Let me double check. Thanks for people who have commented and answered.

Comment: @clwen You should pass 2 arguments, not just 1 to the constructor of `Derived`.

Comment: @songyuanyao I did pass 2 arg to constructor of Derived when I use it.

Answer (score 0):

Both of these options actually do work properly. In C++, objects of derived classes contain the objects of their base classes as separate objects in order to allow for multiple inheritance. You're initializing them before the derived object is created which is correct. I compiled your code using g++ using both constructors separately, and both compiled properly. I think your error may be due to something else.